# What is the significance of using the "!!" operator instead of "!" when using ng-show directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I doing a course in Angular and I've stumbled across an instructor who is showing how to use the ng-show directive in an example. See code below:

```
Name: {{ user.name }} <br /><br />
<div ng-show='!!user.address'>Address:<br />
  {{user.address.street}} <br />
  {{user.address.city}}<br />
  {{user.address.planet}}
</div>
```

The question is, why does the instructor use two exclamation marks instead of one to hide `address`?

For further reference purposes, I include the script.js file:

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    address: {
      street: 'PO Box 123',
      city: 'Secret Rebel Base',
      planet: 'Yavin 4'
    },
    friends: [
      'Han',
      'Leia',
      'Chewbacca'
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) on the "legendary cast-to-bool operator".

Comment: just to put here as reference, !! does type-casting to Boolean

Comment: @Kulbhushan: So does just `!`. :-)

Comment: !! means that the result will be bolean for sure. 
E.g. var doesExists = !!someArray[someIndex];

Comment: but `!` will give you opposite of `user.address` depending on truthy/falsy, whereas `!!` will will type-cast to `true` if `user.address` is truthy and `false` otherwise

Comment: type-cast, interesting terminology